# External Hive table on GCP dataproc not readng data from GCP bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hive, google-cloud-dataproc

I have data in a GCP bucket in the following format:

```
gs://bucket/my_table/data_date=2021-03-26/000
gs://bucket/my_table/data_date=2021-03-26/001
gs://bucket/my_table/data_date=2021-03-27/000
gs://bucket/my_table/data_date=2021-03-27/001
```

I'm creating an external table from the data using:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `my_db.my_table`(
  `col1` string, 
  `col2` string, 
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `data_date` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'field.delim'='\t', 
  'serialization.format'='\t') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'gs://bucket/my_table/'
```

There is no error while creating the table:

```
hive > CREATE EXTENAL TABLE ...
Time Taken: 0.012 seconds
OK
```

However, I'm not able to see any data. None of the following commands return anything even though there are data files in the bucket.

```
hive> show partitions my_db.my_table;
Ok
Time taken: 0.191 seconds

hive> select * from my_db.my_table;
Ok
Time taken: 0.191 seconds
```

I don't see any errors as well. I've verified and I do have read access to the bucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to repair the table to retrieve all the existing partitions in an external table. The repair command recovers all the partitions and updates the Hive metastore.

`MSCK REPAIR TABLE TABLE_NAME`

You can read more about the repair command [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-repair-table.html).